# how to allow textbox values only numbers,round bracket and hyphen in jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

If user adds plus sign,numeric or hyphen or brackets then it should allow the user else throw error
This is my code return false even I pass brackets ,hyphen and numeric value.

How can I achieve below inputs scenarios using jquery or javascript

```
test 1: 647-142-5426 // passed
test 2: +(647)-142-5426 // passed
test 3: (64r)-r42-5426 // failed
test 4: 647r42-5426 // failed
test 5: +16471425426 // passed
```

Here is my code print `false` in console, why ? I wanna achieve above scenarios

```
var plainNumber = '(647)-142-4868';
var re = new RegExp("/^[- +()]*[0-9][- +()0-9]*$/");
console.log(re.test(plainNumber));
```

Comment: You can just use `/^[- +()]*[0-9][- +()0-9]*$/` or `new RegExp("^[- +()]*[0-9][- +()0-9]*$");`

Comment: @Thefourthbird thank you I found solution   var re = new RegExp("^[\\d() +-]+$");

Comment: @Thefourthbird : as posted in the question this wasn't working - /^[- +()]*[0-9][- +()0-9]*$/

Comment: @sqlchild I will work if you either only use the `/` as delimiters, or leave out the delimiters using the double quotes. See https://regex101.com/r/gJtg3X/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird : ok so you mean either use double quotes or use forward slash. using any one will make it work? Thanks...birds are always awesome as they make our mornings energized :)

Answer (score 0):

I found solution

```
var re = new RegExp("^[\\d() +-]+$");
```